# Angular 5 Loops

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array for days as below in my component.ts

```
private days = [{
        'id': 1,
        'day': 'Monday'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'day': 'Tuesday '
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'day': 'Wednesday '
    },
    {
        'id': 4,
        'day': 'Thursday'
    },
    {
        'id': 5,
        'day': 'Friday'
    },
    {
        'id': 6,
        'day': 'Saturday'
    },
    {
        'id': 7,
        'day': 'Sunday'
    }];
```

I am getting  below result from an API call

```
"branchDetails": [
        {
            "user_id": 2,
            "business_branch_id": 3,
            "branch_name": "Synaptech-cloud2",
            "branch_default": 1,
            "gen_dayofweek_id": [
                {
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 2
                }
            ],
            "start_date": "10-09-2013",
            "end_date": "10-09-2017"
        },
        {
            "user_id": 2,
            "business_branch_id": 2,
            "branch_name": "Synaptech-cloud1",
            "branch_default": 0,
            "gen_dayofweek_id": [
                {
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 3
                }
            ],
            "start_date": "10-09-2013",
            "end_date": "10-09-2017"
        }
    ]
```

In view(browser) i need to display a field(Available Days) which should contain days which are not in `gen_dayofweek_id`(field in API result) array

in view i need to show like below

```
available days:  Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday


available days: Tuesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I assume you need 3 loop.

Comment: yes i need 3 loops, but how to iterate them

Comment: change your data structures a bit and you won't need 3 loops. you can make it much more efficient by converting your days collections (both, first and the one in each result from API) into some kind of `Map`. then you're left with checking if `Map` contains some key which is, theoretically, O(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firt, days start at the index 0 and at Sunday. Even though that doesn't apply to your case, you should cope with that.

Next, here is how you can do it

```
for (let branch of branchDetails) {
  const ids = branch.gen_dayofweek_id.map(item => item.id);
  const availableDays = days
    .filter(item => !ids.includes(item.id))
    .map(item => item.day);
  console.log(availableDays);
}
```

This should log arrays of day names.

**EDIT** following my first statement, here is what your data structure should look like :

```
days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

"branchDetails": [{
  "user_id": 2,
  "business_branch_id": 3,
  "branch_name": "Synaptech-cloud2",
  "branch_default": 1,
  "gen_dayofweek_id": [2, 3],
  "start_date": "10-09-2013",
  "end_date": "10-09-2017"
 },
 {
  "user_id": 2,
  "business_branch_id": 2,
  "branch_name": "Synaptech-cloud1",
  "branch_default": 0,
  "gen_dayofweek_id": [2, 4],
  "start_date": "10-09-2013",
  "end_date": "10-09-2017"
 }]
```

With this, you can go even faster

```
for (let branch of branchDetails) {
  const availableDays = days
    .filter((item, index) => !branch.gen_dayofweek_id.includes(index))
  console.log(availableDays);
}
```

Comment: 2 map, 1 for and a filter. and you call it more efficient than O(n^2). Lol :D

Comment: @trichetriche, you are very genious, your answer is awsome, please send your github details, will follow you, please dont forget to share your  git details, and thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @trichetriche if you want to be fast, turn your `days` into map/dictionary/something you can access properties directly with O(1)

Comment: @trichetriche not quite there yet, actually. you've changed it to array of strings (names of days). what i'm talking about is to have a Map where keys would be ids (as they appear in API responses) and values would be days names. then you can have direct predicate if map contains days from API  response (and its predicate by id). if that makes sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but it's not better : a map isn't lighter than an array. In other cases I would have agreed with you, but here we have a key-value data, so we can stay on simple arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
let user_days = [{
  "id": 1
}, {
  "id": 2
}];
user_day_arr = user_days.map(function (obj) {
  return obj.id;
});
let full_days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let result = full_days.filter(day => !user_day_arr.includes(day));
let days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
console.log(result);
//Available days.
result.forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(days[e]);
});
```

Comment: My mobiles text selection was coming over code format button so couldn't do that correctly. Thank you :)